# Explain image.src.match in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, toggle, match

I was following this tutorial and I found some javascript code difficult to understand.

Link to tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb

Code I need to clarify

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
</script>
```

I do not understand what MATCH (in image.src.match) actually means.
Is it something that has a toggling action.
I could not find any useful article for this.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, @elclanrs already provided **[a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** for the `String.prototype.match()` explanation. However, below is an answer which clarifies some things for you.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// capture the image
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

console.log(image.src);                                // http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif
console.log(image.src.match("word-not-in-src-name"));  // null
console.log(image.src.match("bulbon"));                // ["bulbon", index: 32, input: "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif"] 

// image.src.match("bulbon") will return an Array, but it evaluates true in JavaScript
// This is the reason why "Evaluates true!" is printed out to console
if(image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    console.log("Evaluates true!");
}

// To prove my point, "Empty array!" also will be printed out to console
if([]) {
    console.log("Empty array!");
}
```

You can see this yourself from following **[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/P4SRm/)**

Therefore, to get back in your code example:

```
if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
    image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
} else {
    image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
}
```

..means that if bulbon word is in current image `src` attribute, image will be changed to be `pic_bulboff.gif` because execution will move inside the if block, because `image.src.match("bulbon")` will return an Array, (as demonstrated in my above example, and explained in the **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** as well).

Cheers, hopefully you now understand how to check if some word is part of a string in the future :)

Answer (score 7):

`.match()` tests to see if a given string matches a regular expression.

In your example, it tests if `image.src` contains the string `"bulbon"`.

If there is a match, it changes `image.src` to `"pic_bulboff.gif"`

For more information on this function, I recommend:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1):

.match simply implies a test to see weather a string matches the regular expression in this case **bulbon** matching 
 image.src = **"pic_bulbon.gif";** 
if it matches means the bulb is on hence turned off and if its off the else statement makes it turn on again that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var x, text;
    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
        text = "Input not valid";
    } else {
        text = "Input OK";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

image.src.match is simply looking to confirm that the image source file name matches something, in this case "bulbon"

if it matches ("*if*"), a block of code will be run, if it doesn't, a different block of code will be run ("*else*")

Answer (score -2):

the answer is simple, the script only verify the state of the image atributte, if it is on, then it turn it off, and viseversa, if it is Off! , it turn it On!

the script define a initial volue of the image name, in this case "buldon", and control his state.